# Gtk Warning: cannot open display: :0 (for local user!)

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, sudo, user-accounts, xserver, gtk

I know there is a bunch of similar questions around but they are all about a X-Forewarding and SSH sessions.

I got this problem with a local user which is privileged for a specific script...

### The Problem

Under ubuntu 16.04 I want a specific user *guest* to be able to run one specific script */usr/sbin/test.sh* with root privileges (the script make some system settings and mounts for example).

#### Settings

I extend the **/etc/sudoers** file with the following line:

```
guest   ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/test.sh
```

`guest` **is not** in the `sudo` group ! (<-- guess this is the problem)

#### The Script

For sake of simplicity:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

zenity --info --text="Testing Sudo X"
```

The runs fine if executed with `sudo /usr/sbin/test.sh` from a member of the sudo-group or if there are no dialogues to show (*means: making text and operations in a terminal window works without problems*).

If `guest` logs in (via greeter) and start a new gnome-terminal in unity to execute `sudo /usr/sbin/test.sh` it fails with the (hope german is ok) error:

```
No protocol specified
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
Unable to init server: Verbindung ist gescheitert: Verbindungsaufbau abgelehnt

(zenity:19225): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0
```

#### I tried....

- exporting the `$DISPLAY` variable before or in the `test.sh`
- `cp` the `.Xauthority` from anothers `/home/user/` to my `guest`
- generate a xauth cookie with `xauth add` from a `xauth list` of another user
- add `Defaults env_keep += "DISPLAY"` in `/etc/sudoers` *(did a mistake here!!!)*

### Question / Conclusion

None of this worked. I suppose that debugging things on `guest` would generally not help because the command runs with sudo. So I need to find a way to give `guest` a permission for the `$DISPLAY` or `.Xauthority` of sudo just for this single command.

Comment: Are you actually running the script within the GUI? It will not work otherwise.

Comment: I log in as the user via greeter, start a gnome-terminal via unity and type in the command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Ubuntu 16.04 onward, the `DISPLAY` is no longer on `:0`. It is on a number which can vary depending on how many users are simultaneously logged in to the console.

To resolve the problem, you need to configure `sudo` to preserve the `DISPLAY` environment variable.

Add a configuration file to the `/etc/sudoers.d` directory, containing the following:

```
Defaults env_keep += "DISPLAY"
```

This will allow `sudo` to pass the `DISPLAY` environment variable to the program it runs, and those programs will then be able to connect to the correct `DISPLAY`.

Comment: I already tried this (sorry, I updated my question). I put this directly in the /etc/sudoers file after all other Defaults (e.g. Default = env_reset). Is this correct? Unfortunatly no change...

Comment: @MichaelP Did you remove the bit where you manually set `DISPLAY`?

Comment: I tried it with and without `export`. And `echo $DISPLAY` gives `:0` but the user is not allowed to `sudo echo $DISPLAY`. `echo $XAUTHORITY` gives `/home/guest.Xauthority`...so everythings seems ok

Comment: I suggest you log out and log back in.

Comment: ....of course. I am also working on this in a virtualbox so I am reverting changes from time to time to make sure that everything is fresh at the next try.

Comment: You were right. Another script of mine was messing around in the `guest`s homefolder and delted/changed the `.Xauthority`. Changing the `Default` did the trick. So technically this is a duplicated question :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to install xhost

for arch:

```
sudo pacman -S xorg-xhost
```

and then run:

```
xhost +
```

Comment: See my last comment at the accepted answer. It was an environment variable thing...